# Combine duplicate rows on column1 sum column2

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data.

```
Id      ParentId    ProductId   Quantity
215236  19297       16300319    60
215221  19297       16314611    6
215234  19297       16314670    1    <- Duplicate productid
215235  19297       16314670    2    <- Duplicate productid
215195  19297       16314697    20
215205  19297       16321820    75
215216  19297       16329252    10
215233  19297       16331834    9
215224  19297       16519280    40
```

Selecting unique records is easy. Or grouping the data on ProductId is also possible. I need a result
that only contains a unique Product Id with the same parentid and the quantities summed up.

The result should look like this.

```
Id      ParentId    ProductId   Quantity
215236  19297       16300319    60
215221  19297       16314611    6
215234  19297       16314670    3
215195  19297       16314697    20
215205  19297       16321820    75
215216  19297       16329252    10
215233  19297       16331834    9
215224  19297       16519280    40
```

The quantities of the duplicates

```
215234  19297       16314670    1    <- Duplicate productid
215235  19297       16314670    2    <- Duplicate productid
```

should result in

```
215234  19297       16314670    3
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT MIN(id) id,
       ParentId, 
       ProductId, 
       SUM(Quantity) Quantity
FROM [source_table_name]
GROUP BY ParentId, 
         ProductId
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
group by ProductId
```

try

```
group by ParentId, ProductId
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sleeping I guess.

```
SELECT ParentId, ProductId, SUM(Quantity) T FROM [dbo].[InternalOrdersDetail]
where ParentId=19297
group by ParentId, ProductId
```

SUM(Quantity) in select does the job. Facepalm.

Comment: You stated in the question that you also need the smallest id, @Akina ʼs answer handlers that.